# MariaDB Connection refused (NGINX , MariaDB, php-fpm) SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

Tags: nginx, docker-compose, mariadb, fpm

Getting SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused when sending query to MariaDB

Below is the link to my docker-compose build

https://github.com/bocasoftware/docker-compose

--- IMPORTANT This is the data.sql file (NOT in the github repository file was too large but it is on my build):

https://gitlab.com/x-team-blog/docker-compose-php/blob/master/docker/database/data.sql

This is my document tree/layout:

```
myapp
├── docker
│   ├── app
│   │   └── Dockerfile
│   ├── db
│   │   ├── data.sql
│   │   └── Dockerfile
│   ├── docker-compose.yml
│   └── nginx
│       ├── conf.d
│       │   └── default.conf
│       ├── Dockerfile
│       ├── nginx.conf
│       └── sites
│           └── default.conf
└── src
    ├── html
    └── index.php
```

Here is my index.php which has the query:

```
<?php

$value = "World";

try {
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=db;dbname=mydb;charset=utf8mb4', 'myuser', 'secret');

$databaseTest = ($db->query('SELECT * FROM dockerSample'))- 
>fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
} catch (Exception $e) {
print $e->getMessage() . "\n";
}
print "OK\n";
?>

<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello, <?= $value ?>!</h1>

        <?php foreach($databaseTest as $row): ?>
            <p>Hello, <?= $row->name ?></p>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is my docker-compose.yml:

version: '3'

```
services:

  app:
   build:
     context: ./app
   volumes:
      - ../src:/var/www


  nginx:
   build:
     context: ./nginx
   volumes:
      - ../src:/var/www
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./nginx/sites/:/etc/nginx/sites-available
      - ./nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d
   depends_on:
      - app
   ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"


  db:
   build:
     context: ./db
   ports:
      - "3306:3306"
   environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=mydb
      - MYSQL_USER=myuser
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=secret
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=docker
   volumes:
      - ./db/data.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/data.sql
```

I do not understand what is going on. It seems I am reaching MariaDB but it's refusing my connection despite checking ports, user and password and pruning volumes, removing containers, deleting images and building them again from scratch.

docker ps:

```
    CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                NAMES
23ae6d48e413        docker_nginx        "nginx"                  About an hour ago   Up 13 minutes       0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp, 8080/tcp   docker_nginx_1
d84c3b348266        docker_app          "docker-php-entrypoi…"   About an hour ago   Up 13 minutes       9000/tcp                                             docker_app_1
5ba1e7d36f91        docker_db           "docker-entrypoint.s…"   About an hour ago   Up 13 minutes       3306/tcp                                             docker_db_1
```

Build logs:

```
    Building db
Step 1/3 : FROM mariadb:latest
 ---> 2f11cf2ec189
Step 2/3 : CMD ["mysqld"]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 9f5dd0c62210
Step 3/3 : EXPOSE 3306
 ---> Using cache
 ---> fe82aa37cc8d
Successfully built fe82aa37cc8d
Successfully tagged docker_db:latest
Building app
Step 1/4 : FROM php:fpm-alpine
 ---> aac18a94faf7
Step 2/4 : RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 886e00ce8edc
Step 3/4 : CMD ["php-fpm"]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 90bf05e46cc5
Step 4/4 : EXPOSE 9000
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 2e9cb9be36b7
Successfully built 2e9cb9be36b7
Successfully tagged docker_app:latest
Building nginx
Step 1/3 : FROM nginx:alpine
 ---> a624d888d69f
Step 2/3 : CMD ["nginx"]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 767651bd1614
Step 3/3 : EXPOSE 8080 443
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 6fc1df24d4e4
Successfully built 6fc1df24d4e4
Successfully tagged docker_nginx:latest
Starting docker_db_1 ... 
Starting docker_db_1 ... done
Starting docker_app_1 ... 
Starting docker_app_1 ... done
Starting docker_nginx_1 ... 
Starting docker_nginx_1 ... done
Attaching to docker_db_1, docker_app_1, docker_nginx_1
db_1     | 2020-01-06 18:17:42+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 1:10.4.11+maria~bionic started.
app_1    | [06-Jan-2020 18:17:44] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 1
db_1     | 2020-01-06 18:17:43+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
db_1     | 2020-01-06 18:17:43+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 1:10.4.11+maria~bionic started.
app_1    | [06-Jan-2020 18:17:44] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
db_1     | 2020-01-06 18:17:43 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 10.4.11-MariaDB-1:10.4.11+maria~bionic) starting as process 1 ...
db_1     | 2020-01-06 18:17:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
db_1     | 2020-01-06 18:17:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
db_1     | 2020-01-06 18:17:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
db_1     | 2020-01-06 18:17:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
db_1     | 2020-01-06 18:17:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
db_1     | 2020-01-06 18:17:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
db_1     | 2020-01-06 18:17:43 0 [Note] mysqld: O_TMPFILE is not supported on /tmp (disabling future attempts)
db_1     | 2020-01-06 18:17:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 256M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
db_1     | 2020-01-06 18:17:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
db_1     | 2020-01-06 18:17:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
db_1     | 2020-01-06 18:17:44 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
db_1     | 2020-01-06 18:17:44 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
db_1     | 2020-01-06 18:17:44 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
db_1     | 2020-01-06 18:17:44 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
db_1     | 2020-01-06 18:17:44 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.11 started; log sequence number 6837896; transaction id 7512
db_1     | 2020-01-06 18:17:44 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
db_1     | 2020-01-06 18:17:44 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
db_1     | 2020-01-06 18:17:44 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
db_1     | 2020-01-06 18:17:44 0 [Warning] 'user' entry 'root@5ba1e7d36f91' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1     | 2020-01-06 18:17:44 0 [Warning] 'user' entry '@5ba1e7d36f91' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1     | 2020-01-06 18:17:44 0 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@% root@5ba1e7d36f91' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1     | 2020-01-06 18:17:44 0 [Note] Reading of all Master_info entries succeeded
db_1     | 2020-01-06 18:17:44 0 [Note] Added new Master_info '' to hash table
db_1     | 2020-01-06 18:17:44 0 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
db_1     | Version: '10.4.11-MariaDB-1:10.4.11+maria~bionic'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
db_1     | 2020-01-06 18:17:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200106 18:17:45
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add

```
depends_on:
      - db
```

for app

Comment: That makes sense but now I get SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away

Comment: Please specify what you are doing to make this error appear.

Comment: I added depends_on: -db to app on the .yml file and made a new build

Comment: Launched docker containers locally. The application works successfully.[link](https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/4437812/26c553d169538f8763ffe2af54c5b94a)

Comment: Is the data.sql file located in the myapp / docker / db directory?

What does the docker ps and docker logs docker_db_1 command show?

Comment: yes the data.sq file is in the myapp / docker / db director. I have edited the question on top and added the logs.

Comment: Your log is different from mine. Compare https://pastebin.com/0azX2e3D

Entrypoint does not work for you